# How to reduce size of UUID in Doctrine ORM Entity

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, uuid

In my application i'm used UUID as primary key, its working fine but its length too large it contains 32-bit characters. how to reduce length of UUID.

Here my UUID

```
49b0143d-fb8f-4e98-b608-45167748cbc4
```

Expected UUID

```
49b0143d or 49b0143d-fb8f-4e98
```

Answer (score 0):

[Section 3 of RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-3) provides the formal definition of UUID string representations. It's 36 characters - 32 hex digits + 4 dashes. So that the generated uuid's will always have these many numbers of characters. So what you can do is either take/extract the first/desired part of the uuid, by using methods like [substring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) [preg-split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), etc...

**Basic substring() usage (copied from php docs)**

```
<?php
echo substr('abcdef', 1);     // bcdef
echo substr('abcdef', 1, 3);  // bcd
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 4);  // abcd
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 8);  // abcdef
echo substr('abcdef', -1, 1); // f
```

and make your primary key the newly generated one